# Is $\operatorname{Spec}R_S$ homeomorphic to $ \left\{ \mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec}R:\mathfrak p\cap S=\emptyset \right\}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The correspondence theorem for localizations gives a bijection between $\operatorname{Spec}R_S$ and $ \left\{ \mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec}R:\mathfrak p\cap S=\emptyset \right\}$. According to the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572495/when-is-the-set-of-prime-ideals-that-dont-intersect-a-monoid-zariski-open), the latter set is open iff the saturation of $S$ is finitely generated. Are these sets always homeomorphic in this case?

For one direction I think it's enough to show $\uparrow a= \left\{\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec}R_S:\mathfrak p\ni a \right\}$ pulls back to a closed set but I'm having trouble with this. I am not sure about the other direction and can't think of a counterexample either.

Comment: They're always homeomorphic if you give the second set the subspace topology.

Comment: Is there any Algebraic Geometry textbook which doesn't mention this?

Comment: @user26857 I didn't see it mentioned in any of the books I looked at, though they're all introductory. Where would you recommend to learn this?

Comment: Atiyah and Macdonald, exercise 21(i), Chapter 3; Kunz, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry*, Proposition 4.12(b). (You can also use Google to find more.)

Comment: @user26857 thank you.

Comment: @user26857 As far as I remember it's not in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, and if it is, is not at all a the place it should be. ;-)

Comment: Maybe because this is something very easy to figure out?

Comment: @user26857 Absolutely trivial indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely is. This is EGA I, Corollaire (1.2.6), with $S := A \backslash\mathfrak{p}$ which is multiplicative as $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime. It is everywhere on the internet and in almost every algebraic geometry book. (For instance, it is not in Hartshorne's classic "Algebraic Geometry".)

Comment: The last comment seems unnecessary and exaggerated.

Comment: No, as it informs that although the result can be found in EGA I, it is in almost every book of algebraic geometry. So that the OP may feel free to look for other references as well.